# NoReverseMatch Django Exception

Tags: python, django

so I encountered a NoReverseMatch exception in my Django app. It shows me this type of exception:
Reverse for 'user-profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P[^/]+)/$']

###### feed_component.html code:

```
<div>
    {% for room in rooms %}
        <div>
            {% if request.user == room.host %}
            <a href="{% url 'update-room' room.id %}">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'delete-room' room.id %}">Delete</a>
            {% endif %}

            <a href="{% url 'user-profile' room.host.id %}">@{{room.host.id}}</a>
            <h5>{{room.id}} --> <a href="{% url 'room' room.id %}">{{room.name}}</a></h5>
            <small>{{room.topic.name}}</small>
            <hr>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

So my biggest surprise is that in:

```
<a href="{% url 'user-profile' room.host.id %}">@{{room.host.id}}</a>
```

@{{room.host.id}} render excatly what i want on page - id. But this part:

```
{% url 'user-profile' room.host.id %}"
```

Throws exception...
and when i change it to:

```
<a href="{% url 'user-profile' room.host %}">@{{room.host.id}}</a>
```

There is no exceptions, it works ok but i really need that id...

###### urls.py

```
path('profile/<str:pk>/', views.userProfile, name="user-profile"),
```

###### views.py

```
def userProfile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(id=pk)
    rooms = user.room_set.all()
    room_messages = user.message_set.all()
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    context = {'user': user, 'rooms': rooms, 'room_messages': room_messages, 'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'baseapplication/profile.html', context)
```

###### models.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    participants =  models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants', blank=True) 
    
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you make a custom user model?

Comment: No, it is not a custom user model.

Comment: That particular room does not have a host, I think.